# restrict count in availability zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I need to restrict the count az as per region available.

i have try by giving

```
data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]
```

but this create subnet in one AZ only.

sample code :

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}
```

```
//public subnet
resource "aws_subnet" "terraform_public_subnet" {
  count                   = length(var.pub_subnet_cidr)
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.terraform_vpc.id
  cidr_block              = var.pub_subnet_cidr[count.index]
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  availability_zone       = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]

  tags = {
    Name = "terraform-public-subnet"
  }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `count.index` attribute [1] that is made available when using the `count` meta-argument:

```
availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/count#the-count-object

Comment: Hello thanks for answering. I have tried this but main drawback usering [count.index] is. If i have increase my subnet value greater than AZ (availibilty zone) then it throw error that no more az available. 

Eg: in us-east1 zone 6 az available if my total subnet are 8 then last 2 subnet not getting created. 

Expection : i want to restrict [count.index] go max till az available then it should again count from starting.

Comment: This answers your question definitely. However, it is not terraform's or AWS' responsibility for bad design of variables and/or logic.